# What is the best way to bind decimal / double / float values with PDO in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, binding, pdo

It appears the class constants only cover `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`, `PDO::PARAM_INT` and `PDO::PARAM_STR` for binding. Do you just bind decimal / float / double values as strings or is there a better way to treat them?

MySQLi allows the 'd' type for double, it's surprising that PDO doesn't have an equivalent when it seems better in so many other ways.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AFAIK PDO::PARAM_STR is the way to go.

Comment: thanks! i'm probably just going to do this and validate myself.

Comment: For those who didn't know, the syntax is: `$sth->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: If you don't want the bind variable to change from float to string, use bindValue. Using bindParam will change the type.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PDO::PARAM_STR, but for SQLite and other engines this can have unpredictable behaviors.  See this issue for one example: [SQLite HAVING comparison error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105900/sqlite-having-comparison-error)

Answer (score -4):

If you really want to use PDO you'll have to enter it as an `PARAM_INT`, but I never use a specification for `double`.

It is an optional parameter to specify the `PDO` type.

I guess you would better not set the `PDO` type for `double`s.

Comment: I don't think I'd want to lose precision by binding it as an INT but you make a good point about just not specifying the type, thanks.

Comment: Actually, if no param_TYPE is given then PARAM_STR is assumed.

Comment: You don't have and shouldn't bind it as integer or you will lose data! Read @AlixAxel answer instead.

Comment: That used to work some years ago. By nowadays you will lose the precision. Not setting the type uses string as default.