# PDO::PARAM for type decimal?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have 2 database fields

```
`decval` decimal(5,2)
`intval` int(3)
```

I have 2 pdo queries that update them. The one that updates the int works ok

```
$update_intval->bindParam(':intval', $intval, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

but I can't update the decimal field. I've tried the 3 ways below, but nothing works

```
$update_decval->bindParam(':decval', $decval, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update_decval->bindParam(':decval', $decval, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update_decval->bindParam(':decval', $decval);
```

It seems the problem is with the database type `decimal`? Is there a `PDO::PARAM` for a field of type `decimal`? If not, what do I use as a workaround?

Comment: please post the query your preparing

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335081/what-is-the-best-way-to-bind-decimal-double-float-values-with-pdo-in-php

Answer (score 108, accepted):

There isn't any `PDO::PARAM` for decimals / floats, you'll have to use `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

Comment: That was one of the things I tried and didn't work before posting the question here.

Comment: @dmontain: Try defining $decval as a string (eg.: `'1.0'` instead of `1.0`) or use `strval($decval)`.

Comment: @dmontain: It should work out of the box (`PDO::PARAM_STR` is the default when none is specified), and **you shouldn't** change your column data type. Just enclose the value with single or double quotes or `strval()` it, like this: `$update_decval->bindParam(':decval', strval($decval), PDO::PARAM_STR);`.

Comment: @Alix, I have no idea why `strval` isn't working. It sounds like a very logical answer, but something is not working there. I'm trying different combinations to see if any of them would work.

Comment: @dmontain: From the PHP Manual: **Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), *the variable is bound as a reference* and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.** - you have to use `bindValue()` instead if you want to use `strval()`.

Answer (score 0):

UP must use the PDO::PARAM_STR same, and noting that if the column in the database is of type NUMERIC (M, D) or decimal (M, D) should be observed that the M is the number of characters precision should be the total of characters that you can enter, and D the number of decimal places. In the example NUMERIC (10,2) we have 8 houses to places of accuracy and two decimal places. So we have 10 characters in total with 2 reserved for decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, send the decimal parameter like PDO::PARAM_STR, in the sql server store procedure receive it like decimal(int,dec)

PHP

```
$stmt_e->bindParam(':valor_escala_desde', $valor_escala_desde, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

SQL SERVER, STORE PROCEDURE:

```
@valor_escala_desde decimal(18,2),
```

and is done.

Answer (score 0):

use PDO::PARAM_STR for all column types which are not of type int or Bool