# PDO::PARAM_FLOAT does not exist, why?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I wonder why the PDO::PARAM_FLOAT does not exist and what can replace it?

Comment: did the answer helped you? if so accept

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718628/pdoparam-for-type-decimal but only the second question asked here is answered there.

Answer (score 5):

There is none, probably due to implied rounding issues.

Just use `PDO::PARAM_STR` and convert the float to a string using `strval($float)` or `(string)  $float`.

Comment: This won't work because the class constant `PDO::PARAM` doesn't exist. However, if you replace that by `PDO::PARAM_STR` it would work. And you don't have to convert the float to a string.