# How to correctly send a decimal to a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get MySQL decimal field types to work nice and I just can't figure it out. I send a `$_POST['price']` field to a decimal field, for example `3.45`, and it always stores it as `3.00`.

What would I be doing wrong for it to not store the decimals?

Found the solution: [PDO::PARAM for type decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718628/pdoparam-for-type-decimal)

PDO has not decimal storing type, seems like something massive to miss out. Need to store it as a string not a numeric number.

Comment: Could you add some code to the question, please? The PHP you're using to write to the database, at least, and the table definition would also be helpful.

Comment: change data type of the column to decimal (10,2)

Comment: What is the schema definition of that column?

Comment: updated it, found answer

Comment: You definitely have to escape it through `PDO::PARAM_STR`, then DB engine should make the conversion for you "pure insert"-speaking ... If you are doing some counting in your query, it should do that too. If for whatever reason your DB engine doesn't know instruction in a form of arithmetic operators (+, - , * , ...), you could `CAST()`/`CONVERT()` - but I do not recommed that...
Anyway the 2nd main thing is to have the right data type for the column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `floatval()` when converting the `$_POST['price']` variable from a string to a floating point.  This value is what should be stored in your database.

**Be wary though!** Floating point arithmetic is not so great when computing prices due to possible rounding errors.  When dealing with price, I typically use integer arithmetic and then manually put in the decimal point.

So In your example I would store `345` to represent `$3.45`