# PHP MYSQL saving float in database 0.01?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to save number of cents in MySql table as float , but the database is taking it wrong , for example i am saving 0.01, its saved as 0.1 !

is it possible to make this happen ?

My Code ;

```
$return["reward"] = 0.05;

$api->user['balance']  += $return["reward"];

$q = $api->pdo->prepare("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "user
                         SET 
                         balance = :balance
                         WHERE 
                         userid = :userid");

$q->bindParam(":balance" , $api->user['balance']  , PDO::PARAM_INT );
$q->bindParam(":userid" , $api->user['userid'] , PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

the `balance` column TYPE float in database.

Comment: What type does `balance` column have?

Comment: @MaximFedorov type of Float

Comment: Using `PDO::PARAM_INT` will save it using an integer, so not sure how this then comes out as 0.1.  I would have expected either 0 or 1.

Comment: As @Curious_Mind said, you should use `PDO::PARAM_STR`, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718628/pdoparam-for-type-decimal

Maybe your database config is wrong?

Comment: i Did changed it to `PDO::PARAM_STR` still same

Comment: (not a solution but) I wouldn't do it the way you are trying, I would add the value using SQL - `balance = balance + :reward`.

Comment: If I am right, the default "number of decimals" in a float column is one. So your number is rounded up to 1 decimal place: `0.05 => 0.1`

Comment: @dimasdmm how i could achieve this ? by saving the cents like 0.05

Comment: Totally agreed with @NigelRen, with your existing code it would have 0 or 1.

Comment: You should change the precision of your column (I don't know the syntax exactly). I think that the MySQL doc may help you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: Check my answer below and tell me if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fault is not related to your code.

You're using the data type `float` which shouldn't be used to store monetary values.

Change your data type to `decimal` which is considered the best practise for storing monetary values.

You can change it through the webinterface of phpMyAdmin or with a query like so:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname DECIMAL(5,2);
```

This will allow you to store 5 digits before the comma and 2 after, change it to your needs.

Comment: Your description of the digits before the comma is incorrect.
DECIMAL(5,2) has a total number of digits of 5, with 2 for after the decimal point.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with `PDO::PARAM_STR` instead of `PDO::PARAM_INT`.

```
$q->bindParam(":balance" , $return["reward"]  , PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

From [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html)

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
>   PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to
>   M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.
>   For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999
>   when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you
>   insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is
>   999.0001

**Also see** : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: Then it is not related with PDO, it's your db column issue

Comment: the db column type set as Float , i've tried double also same XD

Comment: Yep, I think the same as Curious_Mind. Something is wrong in the database ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change column type to decimal and set Length to 7.2 . Which will be seven numbers before the dot and 2 after it