# Addinng decimals in phpMyAdmin database

Tags: php, sql, pdo, decimal

I'm having a little code, where the user can select a number with or without decimal places. I added the `step` attribute to my `input type="number"`,  So the user can insert decimals, as shown:

```
    <form method="post" >
    <input type='number' name='price' min='1' max='30' step=".01" required> 
    <input type='submit' name='submit'> 
    </form>
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    try{
            require("conecction.php");
            $db->beginTransaction();
            $ins = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO items (price) VALUES (?)");
            $ins->bindParam(1,$_POST['price']);
            $ins->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
      $db->rollBack();
      echo "<p style=color:red;> There was an connection error.<p>";
      die($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

and my SQL table has the following format:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
)
```

This code is functional and inserts the data into the DB as expected to be, but only it is inserting the closest number to the decimal point, for example the user inserts 21.4 I get 21 in my DB.

Comment: Is it correct in `$_POST` but being lost in the INSERT, or incorrect in `$_POST`?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the parameter type via the third parameter of bindparam? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718628/pdoparam-for-type-decimal

Comment: Please show us `var_dump($_POST['price']);` to verify your input.

Comment: @droopsnoot I have used `var_dump`, to check the value of it in `$_POST` , it's correct, but when it reaches the DB it comes without any decimals

Comment: @CBroe , I have just tried it, still I'm not getting the decimal points

Comment: @CBroe, the docs specify `PARAM_STR` as the default, which is the required constant for decimals/floats as you correctly pointed out via the answer you referred to.

Comment: @RoAchterberg  it's ouputing this :string(4) "21.4"

Comment: What happens, when you do `$ins->bindValue(1, '21.4');` for testing purposes?

Comment: @CBroe it also inserts without the points

Comment: And if you try `$ins->bindValue(1, '21,4');` instead? (Maybe there’s some sort of locale setting that influences what the database considers to be a decimal point?)

Comment: Please share `DESCRIBE items;` just to verify your assumption of the table definition.

Comment: @CBroe, [locale support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html) seems to be limited to date/time values. I think they force ANSI on input, and allow for more freedom in output.

Comment: @RoAchterberg thank you, I fixed it, I thought that the price column was defined as decimal(6,2) , but it was decimal(6,0).

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping

Comment: Great! Happy coding.

Answer (score -2):

Change the **data type** of the field to FLOAT
As you assign the float datatype in DB then you will be able to save integer
as well as float decimal values.

http://prntscr.com/1uvulon

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained _why_ this solves the problem.

Comment: @RoAchterberg _can_ an answer suggesting to use a float type for a price field, that is supposed to contain a currency amount, _ever_ be good? I don’t think it can.

Comment: @CBroe, I'm inclined to agree with you on that.

Comment: I have tried FLOAT, DOUBLE, and DECIMAL, all are not inserting the decimal point