# pdo + ms sql server gives different results with binded or hard coded parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Pdo results with bound values are different than hard coded values.

```
$q = $conn->prepare('SELECT 0.27 * 0.08 * SUM(n) as ok, 
                        :i * SUM(n) as notOK 
                    from mytable 
                    group by id'); 
$q->bindValue(':i', 0.27*0.08, PDO::PARAM_STR); // tax
$q->execute();
var_dump($q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Results:

```
["ok"]=> "313.095888" 
["notOK"]=> "289.9036" 

["ok"]=> "80.601048" 
["notOK"]=> "74.6306"
...
```

ok != notOK, but it should (ok is correct).

My question is why?

*details, what you asked for:*

- column 'n' and 'id' is int
- tested on php7.4 + pdo for mssql (both
  linux and win)
- it works with PDO::PARAM_INT (thanks for the suggestion :), although the suggested bind type is PDO::PARAM_STR for decimal [PDO::PARAM for type decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718628/pdoparam-for-type-decimal) )

Comment: PDO::PARAM_STR might be a problem?

Comment: Leaving out `* SUM(n)` from the query might shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: Try `$q->bindValue(':i', 0.27*0.08, PDO::PARAM_STR_CHAR);` that worked for me

Comment: What driver do you use to connect to SQL Server and what are the actual data types of `id` and `n` columns?

Comment: I'm able to return the expected result with `PDO::PARAM_INT` (`$q->bindValue(':i', 0.27*0.08, PDO::PARAM_INT);`). I'm using PHP Driver for SQL Server.

Comment: siggemannen: bingo! :)

although the suggested bind type is PDO::PARAM_STR for decimal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718628/pdoparam-for-type-decimal