# Yii2 - ActiveRecord - type casting

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, pdo, yii2

in yii2 activerecord float,double,decimal datatype of mysql not support ! (Or I'm wrong)
when i access to this column(float,double,decimal) , yii2 return string.

how i can type casting float,double,decimal datatype of mysql to php float ?

```
mytable(id int, f1 float, f2 double, f3 decimal(10,2))
```

for example in activerecord class :

```
public function filters(){
   // return [['f1','f2','f3'] => 'float', ...];
}
```

Comment: How do you retrieve data exactly?

Comment: i think your mean is : `$f1_float_but_string = mytable::findOne(1)->f1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yii returns string for unsigned integers and floating numbers. That's because typically DBMS type can represent more than PHP and we want to preserve precision.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about Yii internals but I can answer for mysql and PDO.

First of all, for the `decimal` type you cannot get anything but string, as it's the very point of this data type.

For the rest, to make PDO return int and double values with corresponding types from mysql, you have to make sure that **both** [mysqlnd-based driver is installed and emulation mode is turned off](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation). Given that, PDO will return you proper data types from a prepared statement.

Comment: thanks, hmmm i think this is not related with my question. EMULATE affected on send query. do this affected output result ?

Comment: i think this question has nothing to do yii2 [What is the best way to bind decimal / double / float values with PDO in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335081/what-is-the-best-way-to-bind-decimal-double-float-values-with-pdo-in-php)

Comment: this question you posted link to has nothing to do with returning results in the first place.