# Yii2: problems with findOne query on float value

Tags: mysql, yii2

Database field name with datatype `value float(5,2)`

```
Inserted value
7.80
78.00
```

My query in modal

```
$checkValue = static::find()->where(['value' => $this->value])->one();
```

If i passed `$this->value`equal to 78.00 or 78.000 then it returns proper result.

But if I pass 7.80 or 7.8 then 0 rows are returned. Why?

Comment: What happens when $this->value is a _string_ `'7.80'`?

Comment: Its give me 0 result if i passed it in string. Its work with like query....

Comment: Can you check the database directly?

Comment: yes in database query its working fine
SELECT * FROM `value_master` WHERE `value`=7.8

Comment: `Yii` returns string for `unsigned` integers and `floating` numbers. That's because typically `DBMS` type can represent more than `PHP` and we want to preserve precision.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840490/yii2-activerecord-type-casting

Comment: Can you just dump the value as is? I mean, do SELECT * by the primary key of this row, and output it via some Dumper interface?

Answer (score 0):

i suspect internally mysql treats `7.8` as something like `7.800000000001` so you cannot get a result if you compare with a fixed value.

you may have come across mysql's reference manuals on datatypes.
please note the following:

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.
>
> **Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems**. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies. For more information, see Section [B.5.4.8, “Problems with Floating-Point Values”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html)
>
> For maximum portability, code requiring storage of approximate numeric data values should use FLOAT or DOUBLE PRECISION with no specification of precision or number of digits.

---

for most applications you can safely use a [fixed point type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html).
essentially using `decimal(5,2)` instead of `float(5,2)` ensuring that any value displayed is the exact value stored internally.
when applicable rounding happens on insert with the "round half up" rule **to the precision you specifed** and is somewhat more intuitive and easy to manage

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue with double datatype

```
value double(5,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the value is float in where condition, use like this:

```
$checkValue = static::find()->where(['<>', 'value', $this->value])->one();
```