# PHP Submitting a value with a dot or comma to a database (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, decimal

I have a small form which submits data to a database and shows it back on the screen again. I've got it almost working, but I'm struggling with dots (.) and comma's (,) in a textfield in PHP. Whenever I put in 77.50 or 77,50 as a value in a PHP textfield, nothing is submitted to the database. When I just enter 77, everything goes well and it's submitted. If I type the query in SQL self all goes well too:

```
INSERT INTO prijzen (inkoopprijs) VALUES ('77.50');
```

I have tried the following anwswers in the topics below with no luck:

- [PDO::PARAM for type decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718628/pdoparam-for-type-decimal)
- [What is the best way to bind decimal / double / float values with PDO in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335081/what-is-the-best-way-to-bind-decimal-double-float-values-with-pdo-in-php)

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Probably something silly I forgot to do...

Here is the code/column I use for the decimal bit:
The column in the database:

- Name: inkoopprijs
- type: DECIMAL (5,2)

```
    $inkoopprijs = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"inkoopprijs",FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
    $iQuery = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO prijzen (inkoopprijs) VALUES (:inkoopprijs)");
    $iQuery->bindParam("inkoopprijs", $inkoopprijs);
        
    If ($iQuery->execute())
        {
            echo "Added to the database.";
        }
    Else
        {
            echo "Something went wrong.";
        }

    echo "<td><font color=black font face='Chiller' font size = '6'>" . "\xE2\x82\xAc" . number_format($data["inkoopprijs"],2,",",".") . "</font></td>";
```

Comment: you can use php function

Comment: Do a `var_dump($inkoopprijs)` after your `filter_input()` to see what it actuall returns.

Comment: it outputs: php:89:string '7725' (length=4) (and I entered 77.25)

Comment: See, I told you it was something silly. Thank you very much! I will update my question with the link you provided!